# Вывод на LCD экран

Tags: arduino

Есть LCD Keypad Shield 1602. ([Описание шилда](https://arduinomaster.ru/platy-arduino/arduino-lcd-keypad-shield/)). Хочу вывести на экран информацию. Пишу такой скетч

```c
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void print(String msg) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(msg);
  Serial.println(msg);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  print("Hello");
  delay(1000);
}
```

В итоге в терминале сообщения есть, а не экране нет.

Пробовал опрашивать кнопки шилда - кнопки работают.

Что я делаю не так и почему текст может не выводиться на экран?

Comment: Фон знакомест на LCD затемнен? Курсор есть?

Comment: @insolor Нет. Сплошная синяя заливка

Comment: Скорее всего инициализация не происходит по какой-то причине. Так сходу не придумаю как это отдебажить. Только этот пример не работает, есть примеры кода, которые работают?

Comment: С библиотекой LiquidCristal идут примеры, можно их попробовать запускать, только пины в создании объекта прописать правильные для этого шилда.

Comment: @insolor Какие могут быть еще примеры, если не работает обычный вывод текста? Это же не тач-скрин, где можно еще и считывать с экрана

Comment: @insolor Вот я взял пины из описания этого шилда https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZGp4.png

Comment: Попробуйте покрутить потенциометр контрастности. В обоих крайних положениях экран не будет нормально показывать.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов вы правы. Именно так все и решилось. Забыл я за этот вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итого задача решена. Было две проблемы

1. Была выкручена контрастность. После того, как я отверткой подкрутил потенциометр (голубой параллелепипед на плате)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   я увидел знакоместа. Но они все были в виде заполненных прямоугольников.
2. Т.к. я новичок в ардуине, то все делал аккуратно и забыл правило "вставить до хруста". В итоге у меня шилд только слегка касался контактов ардуины. Когда вставил нормально, то все заработало